# having generic internal procedure with ifort compiler

Tags: generics, compiler-construction, fortran, intel-fortran, fortran2003

The following works with gfortran or f95, but not with ifort:

```
  interface add
     procedure addr, addi
  end interface add

  real a, b
  integer i, j

  data a, b, i, j /1.0, 2.0, 1, 2/


  call add(a,b)
  call add(i,j)

  stop
  contains 

  subroutine addr(x,y)
  real x, y
  print *, x+y
  return
  end subroutine addr

  subroutine addi(m, n)
  integer m, n
  print *, m+n
  return
  end subroutine addi

  end
```

ifort returns this error:

```
  error #6643: This statement is incorrectly positioned.
            procedure addr, addi
   ---------^
  error #8168: Parentheses are required after the PROCEDURE keyword.
            procedure addr, addi
  ---------^
```

Assume that any module procedure can not be used (we don't want to have addr and addi in a module) and ifort has to be used as a compiler.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: FWIW, this works with pgf90 10.6-7

Comment: The code posted compiles without errors or warnings with ifort 13.0.0.  I suggest you go on holiday for about 6 months, come back when that version of the compiler is generally available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intel Fortran 12.1.5 does not support the form or meaning of a *procedure-stmt* (the statement inside the interface block that the error refers to) without the leading MODULE keyword.

(Consequently the compiler has classified the line as a *procedure-declaration-stmt* - hence the two errors.)

The form of the procedure statement without the leading module was introduced in the Fortran 2003 standard, the ability to have internal procedures as specific procedures behind a generic interface was introduced in the Fortran 2008 standard.

There is no work around, given your stated requirement of not being able to use module procedures, until Intel Fortran supports that particular Fortran 2008 feature.

Comment: I assumed that "procedure statement" is a part of standard fortran. It is disappointing that they don't have this feature in ifort. I have posted this question, because we have a big code that should be compiled with any fortran compiler. ifort generally does a good job in optimizing the code, but this would be a drawback. I looked at their language reference pdf [file](http://www.cita.utoronto.ca/MISC/computing_guide/docs/Intel_Fortran_v8.1/fcompindex.htm) and there is nothing there neither.

Comment: That form of procedure statement is part of the Fortran 2003 standard.  It was not part of the Fortran 95 standard.  There are only two or three compilers on the market that claim to be compliant with the full Fortran 2003 standard (Intel Fortran is not one of them).  There are many more compilers that claim Fortran 95 compliance.  If you want your code to work with "any fortran compiler" you perhaps need to take that into account.

Comment: According to the promotional materials from Intel: "... support _nearly all of Fortran 2003_ and key features in the Fortran 2008 standard" (emphasis mine) Supported `INTERFACE` construct syntax is given on page 2923 of the compiler manual and it shows `[MODULE PROCEDURE name-list]...`.